# How to use custom font in VS Code(Windows) without admin privilege to install the font?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

I don't have Admin privilege on my working PC(Windows 7), so I can't install custom font(Fira Code) into my system. Is there a way to use such font without installing in VS Code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Find a ugly workaround for this issue: using webfont.

1. Open Help -> Toggle Developer Tools in the menu
2. Paste below js codes and execute in the Console of DevTools to setup 'Fira Code' font face.

```js
var styleNode = document.createElement('style'); 
styleNode.type = "text/css"; 
var styleText = document.createTextNode(`
    @font-face{
        font-family: 'Fira Code';
        src: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonsky/FiraCode/master/distr/eot/FiraCode-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonsky/FiraCode/master/distr/woff2/FiraCode-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonsky/FiraCode/master/distr/woff/FiraCode-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
             url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonsky/FiraCode/master/distr/ttf/FiraCode-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }`); 
styleNode.appendChild(styleText); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);
```

3. Make sure 'Fira Code' is the first parameter in the Font Family settings.
4. Enable Font Ligatures settings, otherwise ">=" won't be transferred to "≥"
5. (Optional) in the Sources tab of DevTools, create a new snippet with the codes, and right click the new created file to run. It can be preserved ever after restart the application.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the snippet is preserved after restarting but it's necessary to run it each time you start the application. It's still better than using default fonts! I wonder if this could possibly be made to run as a vs code extension automatically, maybe?

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to do this without having to run the snippet every time you stat up VS Code.

1. Go to `File > Open Folder`
2. Navigate to your VS Code installation, and then go to:

   `resources > app > out > vs > code > electron-browser > workbench`
   Open that folder.
3. Edit `workbench.js` using VS Code and add the Tai's snippet to the end of it.
4. Save
5. Do `Ctrl+R` to reload the window and you should be done!

Again, make sure that you have Fira Code as the first option in your Font Family settings within VS Code, and make sure that font ligatures are enabled.

Comment: I cannot seem to find this "resources" folder in my Appdata install

Comment: Thanks, this is useful for me! However, it does cause a message in the VS Code ("Installation appears to be corrupt [Unsupported]") with reference to this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported, which can be undesirable for many users.

Answer (score 1):

Tai Zhang's [great little hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124991/4940283) can be automated with the [Monkey Patch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch) extension.

After installing [Monkey Patch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch), paste Tai's code into a new file, e.g. `%USERPROFILE%\vscode-monkeypatch-modules\custom-fonts.js`.

Now add the file to your `settings.json`, e.g.:-

```json
"monkeyPatch.folderMap": {
    "my-custom-modules" : "~/vscode-monkeypatch-modules",
},
"monkeyPatch.browserModules": [
    "my-custom-modules/custom-fonts"
]
```

Comment: How do I add multiple fonts (for fast switching), is that even possible?

Comment: Tai Zhang's code is making a style node and appending it into the head. You should be able to make as many nodes as you like, one per font, and append them all into the head.

Comment: This hack should be less and less necessary - newer versions of Windows 10 let you right-click-install fonts without admin rights, and older versions of Windows 10 let you use RegisterFont to do the same (see my other answer).

Comment: @NZTony when using portable VSCode from a flash drive it's a hustle install fonts on each machine VSCode is launched at...so this hack is very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to hack VS Code - you can add per-session fonts to windows without admin privileges with the free [RegisterFont](https://github.com/tsukasa/RegisterFont) app, or write your own tiny app to call [AddFontResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew) on each font.

I whipped up a C# app, put the .exe in my user-fonts directory, then `paste shortcut` it into my user startup folder (which you can find by typing `shell:startup` into the `Run...` dialog):-

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int AddFontResource(string lpFilename);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool RemoveFontResource(string lpFilename);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint message, int wParam, int lParam);

    static void Main()
    {
        var exePath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
        var fontFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
        var fontCache = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "UserSessionFontCache");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fontCache);

        foreach (var fontPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fontFolder, "*.ttf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var targetPath = Path.Combine(fontCache, Path.GetFileName(fontPath));
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(targetPath)) RemoveFontResource(targetPath);
                File.Copy(fontPath, targetPath, true);
            }
            catch { /* font in use */ }
            if (File.Exists(targetPath)) AddFontResource(targetPath);
        }

        SendMessage(0xFFFF /* HWND_BROADCAST */, 0x001D /* WM_FONTCHANGE */, 0, 0);
    }
}
```