# Add font to Visual Studio Code without installing

Tags: windows, fonts, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to add fonts like Fira Code to Visual Studio Code without installing on Windows?

I would like to add one to Visual Studio Code on the machine at my workplace, but there installing anything requires admin rights which are not granted to the employees.

Comment: I think you can't, to set a font in vs code, it should be installed in your machine

Comment: There are 2 useful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124991/758029
Worked for me!